# How can I fill a dataset from an "object" data source?

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I want to add a "object" as a data source...

then

fill a "dataset" using the datasource?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create your own table(s) within the DataSet object and write your own method to iterate through your objects and generate rows for them. I'm partial towards strongly-typed DataSets, so you could design the DataSet through the XSD designer and have the DataTable classes ready for you to consume. It sounds a little intense at first, but if your object isn't that complex, it won't take that long to put together.

At a little more elegant level, you can look into some ORM (Object-Relational Modeling) tools such as [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org) or the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) to do most (if not all) of the heavy lifting for you, you just need to setup the proper configuration.

There are pros and cons to each, you'll need to evaluate that for yourself.